# Best cross-platform activity statistics software?

Tags: statistics

Right now I ended up using ActivityWatch because it has almost everything I need and a very good grouping system, but it has a very huge flaw - no synch between devices. Are there any similar apps with such a feature?
The main points I would like a program to have are:

- Tracks apps AND browser tabs (at least on PC, very important)
- Synch between devices
- Good grouping system
- Would be perfect if it were free

Thank you in advance!